# How to display selected file to a textbox GUI using powershell?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I want to select a file from a folder with GUI, then display the selected file name to a text box. I tried it but after I select the file, it does not display in the text box.

```
 Function File ($InitialDirectory)
    {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
        $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
        $OpenFileDialog.Title = "Please Select File"
        $OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
        $OpenFileDialog.filter = “All files (*.*)| *.*”
        If ($OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq "Cancel") 
        {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("No File Selected. Please select a file !", "Error", 0, 
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Exclamation)
        }   $Global:SelectedFile = $OpenFileDialog.FileName

    } 

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

    $Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.ClientSize                 = '576,259'
    $Form.text                       = "Process"
    $Form.TopMost                    = $false
    #----------------------

    $ChooseML_L                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
    $ChooseML_L.AutoSize             = $true
    $ChooseML_L.width                = 25
    $ChooseML_L.height               = 10
    $ChooseML_L.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(128,45)
    $ChooseML_L.ForeColor            = "#000000"

    $SelectML                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $SelectML.multiline              = $false
    $SelectML.width                  = 100
    $SelectML.height                 = 20
    $SelectML.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(123,100)

    $ChooseML                        = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $ChooseML.AutoSize               = $true
    $ChooseML.width                  = 100
    $ChooseML.height                 = 20
    $ChooseML.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(123,69)
    $ChooseML.ForeColor              = "#ffffff"
    $ChooseML.BackColor              = "#093c76"

    $ChooseML.Add_Click({$SelectML.Text = File})

    $Form.Controls.AddRange(@($ChooseML, $ChooseML_L, $SelectML))
    [void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

My expectation, after I select the file, it will display to a text box.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are not returning anything from your `File` Select function.

Just add this to the function.

```
Function File ($InitialDirectory)
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.Title = "Please Select File"
    $OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = “All files (*.*)| *.*”
    If ($OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq "Cancel") 
    {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("No File Selected. Please select a file !", "Error", 0, 
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Exclamation)
    }
    $Global:SelectedFile = $OpenFileDialog.FileName
    Return $SelectedFile #add this return
}
```

Either that, or assign the value of `$global:SelectedFile` to `$SelectML.Text`

Comment: Yes, I did it. But it return include the path of the file that I selected. I just want to display the file name without the path.

Comment: @Job You can use `$Global:SelectedFile = $OpenFileDialog.SafeFileName` to get just the file name. If you have multiple files returning just change it to `$Global:SelectedFile = $OpenFileDialog.SafeFileNames` That will return an array.